# return value of scanf() for string

Tags: c, scanf, return-value

This code 
...

```
void main()
{

char str[5];

long int c=scanf("%s",str);
printf("\n%p %p %p %p", c, &str[0], &str[1], &str[4]);

}
```

...

gave output:
...

```
bhjun //thats the input

0x1 0x7ffe98cdf5a3 0x7ffe98cdf5a4 0x7ffe98cdf5a7
```

...

I can understand the relation between memory address of the string characters, but which memory address did scanf() return, why in hexadecimal, and why does it return memory address for string while it returns number of inputs for numeric and character constants?

Comment: Read the format description for printf() and "%p"; that explains hex format. Also read about the result value of scanf(). Then be aware that it makes no sense to output integer `c` as pointer. Best of all, try to read a book on C that covers debugging also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) function returns the number of successful conversion specifications which assigned a value (so `%*s` isn't counted but `%s` is), or it returns EOF.  So, you could, in principle, get EOF, 0 or 1 from the `scanf()` call you show — in practice, you will get EOF or 1 because `%s` will accept any characters that aren't white space.  If the conversion was for a number, you might readily get 0 returned — the input is a letter or punctuation.

Comment: But why did it show a hex code instead of integer in case of successful conversion, like it did with others?